# is there some significance in their relationship between Haman and Daniel?

Tags: tanach, purim, megillat-esther

The Gemara says that memuchan was Haman, but in Targum Sheni it says it was Daniel. Also regarding hasach the regular Targum identifies as Daniel and says Haman killed him. My question is, is there some connection between Haman and Daniel? Or significance on there relationship if there is any?

Comment: Can you clarify, with an [edit] to your question, what you mean by connection?

Comment: Very related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6138/

Answer (score 9):

They have the same numerical value.

ה = 5

מ = 40

ן = 50

**5 + 40 + 50 = 95**

ד = 4

נ = 50

י = 10

א = 1

ל = 30

**4 + 50 + 10 + 1 + 30 = 95**

This equivalency is noted by [R. Solomon Alkabetz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Halevi_Alkabetz) in [Manos Halevi](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39949&pgnum=236)

Comment: Ok, and your point is?

Comment: @ezra I don't know. The question simply asked for a correlation, so I gave one. It didn't ask to explain the meaning of the correlation.