# Why is Daniel called Memuchan?

Tags: megillat-esther

There is a machlokes who Memuchan is. One opinion is that it is Haman.
According to that opinion he is called Memuchan because he prepared [in hebrew: muchan] himself to be punished ([Megillah 12b](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.12b.11?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi)).

According to another opinion he is Daniel ([Pirkei D'Rabbi Eliezer Chapter 49](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pirkei_DeRabbi_Eliezer.49.13?lang=bi)).
According to the opinion that it is Daniel, why was he called Memuchan?

Comment: Great question Simcha Zeidman! Welcome to Mi Yodeya!

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6138/memuchan-hasach-daniel

Comment: They also say that Hatach was Daniel

Comment: It must be that the opinion which says that Hasach was Daniel holds that Memuchan was Haman.      Does anyone know who the opinion that says that Memuchan was Daniel says that Hasach was?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This opinion also appears in [**Targum Sheni**](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=602297&pagenum=98) to Megillah.

The Targum itself explains the reason. I'll copy for you the Hebrew Translation from **Pas'shegen HaKesav**:

> ויאמר ממוכן הוא דניאל ולמה נקרא שמו ממוכן כי כאשר גלו שבט יהודה לבבל גלו עמהם חנניה מישאל ועזריה ודניאל היה בגולה ונעשו על ידיהם נסים ונפלאות ועוד נגזר מן השמים כי ושתי המלכה תהרג ע"י דניא ע"כ נקרא שמו ממוכן מזומן.
>
> **And Memuchan said**. He is Daniel. And why is he called Memuchan? Since when the tribe of Yehudah was exiled to Babylonia, Chananiah, Mishael, and Azariah were exiled with them. And Daniel was already in exile. And many miracles and wonders were performed because of them. Furthermore, it was decreed from Heaven that Queen Vashti would be killed through Daniel. Therefore, he is called Memuchan, meaning Mezuman (prepared/ready).

[**Midrash Panim Acherim** § 2](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=627611&pagenum=298) writes similarly. [**Rav Shlomo Buber**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salomon_Buber) there writes that this is the source for Targum Sheni.

It sounds like two reasons. I don't follow the first reason. Perhaps he means that Daniel was in exile before the rest, so he was ready for them when they too were exiled? The second explanation is simple enough.

However, [**Radal**](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21858&st=&pgnum=267) to Pirkei DRabbi Eliezer ad. loc. § 77 brings the first explanation from the Targum, and explains its intent to mean that Daniel was prepared for miracles (see below). He says this refers to the miracles he performed in Babylonia with Nevuchadnetzar and Belshatzar.

[**Otzar HaMidrashim**](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=52639&&pagenum=48) brings from **Midrash Chaseiros VeYeseiros** that Daniel was Memuchan, since he was prepared for miracles. I'm not sure which miracles it's referring to. Perhaps the miracle of Purim? Or perhaps the intent is like the **Radal** above.

It also brings from **Midrash Agadas Esther** that Daniel was called Memuchan because Daniel said upon Vashti the explicit name of Hashem, causing her to have a blemish (presumably causing her to not come when summoned by Achashverosh). This is a play on the word ממוכן, seeing it as if it spells מום כאן, as in "here is a blemish".

[**Torah Sheleimah**](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=150138&pagenum=52) ad. loc § 163 brings something else from Midrash Agadas Esther. He writes that Daniel was prepared to bring about Esther's merits (presumably to save the Jewish people). He says this also the intent of Pirkei D'Rabbi Eliezer that you started with.

Answer (score 0):

Also…,.
name is mentioned first in 1’/14”
last of seven names and there targum sheni
says these are names of different places
and memuchan is yerushalaim
and that it is referring to daniel who came from there

so memuchan is (ירושלים ( דניאל